# Create desktop Entry for Eclipse IDE in Debian 10

Tags: debian, eclipse, ide

I am not expert in linux but can find my way around it most of the time. I have install Eclipse IDE for Debian 10 and tried to create a desktop entry. This is what I did:

Created a eclipse.desktop file  in `~/.local/share/applications` directory.

These are the contents of the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse Java IDE
Comment=Eclipse Java IDE
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=/home/testaccount/eclipse/cpp-2020-03/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/home/testaccount/eclipse/cpp-2020-03/eclipse/icon.xpm
Categories=GNOME;Application;Development;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
```

Saved filed and gave exec permission with `chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`.

I rebooted my Debian VM already and I do not have the icon still. I currently created a soft link to it in the meantime. Not sure why the desktop entry is not working yet, I am not sure what I am missing.

Thank you.